# WPF: Need a TextBox to have some of the advanced features of a DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

My application implements a simple *Calculation Chain*, as spreadsheets do. It has a `TextBox` into which the user types some numerical values and as soon as it is **edited**, the code proceeds to update all the dependent fields.

My scarce experience with `TextBox` tells me that an event can be triggered each time the user clicks a character. This behavior is not good: Suppose the person types the value "1234": the calculation chain would be performed for "1", next for "12", then for "123" and finally for "1234".

I need a way to know when the editing ended. Maybe the rectangle could become blue upon **Enter**, like those in `DataGrid`. The user should be able to leave with the **Tab** key or by clicking elsewhere.

Also: an empty TextBox is not the same thing as containing a zero! An empty TextBox's content should be recognized as undefined.

The question then is: What kind of control and ancillary functions do I need?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to perform your calculation when the **TextBox** has **LostFocus**

In your view you will have

```
<Window...>

    <TextBox LostFocus="Perform_Calculation"/>

</Window>
```

Then in your code-behind define that method

```
private void Perform_Calculation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // calculation logic here...
    // probably also where you will check if the Text is empty (nothing to be done)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a TwoWay binding and the default **PropertyChangeTrigger** on a **TextBox** should be **LostFocus** - so you should only get your property update when the user has moved away from the TextBox.

Note that this won't satisfy your hope of also handling it on the press of an **Enter**, as the **TextBox** would still have focus. To enable this also, extend it slightly

```
<Window...>

    <TextBox LostFocus="Perform_Calculation" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>

</Window>

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        // perform calculation here (probably method that you will also call
        // from LostFocus handler to avoid duplication)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the user will not be able to end the editing by pressing <Enter>?

Comment: The answer should be updated to provide such an extension for this functionality.